# Manhwa/manga about a female main character who gets married and then gets kidnapped

Tags: story-identification, manga

I don't recall the beginning of the story, but at some point the female main character and her new husband (duke/prince/don't know anymore) come home to his territory. This is mostly covered in snow.

The daughter of the family who watches the castle in the absence of the lord is quite jealous of her and tries to harm her. The daughter gets sent to a monastery. After some time she tells some bandits to enter the castle secretly and the female protagonist gets kidnapped. The lord saves her and the daughter gets executed. (The family too, I think.)

The lord is tasked to hold back some kind of monsters that come over a mountain. They look like some kind of humanoid, but stronger with white eyes and horns, I think, and they can withstand the cold.

I read it in 2020 or maybe early 2021. I think it was full color.

Comment: When and where did you read this?

Comment: Was this in full colour or mostly black & white, and what colour was the female lead's hair?

Comment: I think in 2020 maybe early 2021. I think is was full color.

Comment: "Dear my Hunny Bunny"? Snowy area; I think there's a castellan. 25 chapters in and there's been a kidnapping, but more of the "Emperor's orders; I'm taking the girl" variety. It's possible there's a bandit-kidnapping later. No mentions of monsters. It certainly feels like a good match, but the details aren't matching up well enough.

Comment: No I dont think it is "Dear my Hunny Bunny" Sorry but when i think about the story the Kidnapper was a lord  from another teritory

Answer (score 1):

This manga is called "[Marriage of Convenience](https://m.tapas.io/series/marriage-of-convenience-comic/info)" and you can find it on Tapas.

> Description
>
> Bianca de Arno was a ruthless countess in the Kingdom of Sevran, infamous for being a wicked and selfish wife. While her husband, Count Zachary de Arno, bravely risked his life out on the battlefield, she sat at home and spent his money. It wasn’t until her final day that Bianca realized the error of her ways. Before she dies, Bianca prays for a second chance, swearing she will do better, and wakes up in her 19-year-old body. With her second chance, Bianca starts to see everything in a new light… starting with her husband.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you please give us some details about this manga, including a synopsis and perhaps a link so the person who asked the question can tell if this is correct?